# Can we detach SignerHere Tabs from anchorSting?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have 2 recipients in my envelope with 'SignHere' tabs and corresponding anchor strings. As I understand these anchor strings are used to place the tabs in right location on a document. Now once the envelope is created, if I try to move one 'Sign Here tab all tabs move. Is there any way to specify in the *createEnvelope* request JSON to ungroup these anchor strings?

Comment: If you want to treat the tabs individually why don't you use different anchor string for each tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to ungroup anchor tabs in the [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

Looks like you want each of the tabs to have different properties. In that case, its better to use different anchor strings for different tab groups.

You can however **UnGroup** anchor tabs after the envelope is created. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45381178/1219543)

Here is some good [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs) about anchor tabs.

Comment: I need to be un-group signhere tabs for a single user on a document which is about 16-20 pages and I have to handle 2 users. So different anchor strings for each page not a practical solution in my case. I get a json response back, but I am not able to make a PUT request with success. My JSON structure is wornf. Can you please post an example of PUT /v2/accounts/*******/envelopes/***/recipients/1/tabs

Comment: Please post a new question as it will be easier to answer there.

Comment: I have posted a new question with all the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357930/docusign-rest-api-un-group-tabs